# URL rewrinting from www.example.com to www.example.com/beta

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

His friends, currently my website is set up in the "beta" folder in my root just like

www.example.com/beta

Now if any user enters the following URL

www.example.com

then he should be automatically redirected to the first URL, any ideas? I know this can be done through .htaccess but i am not sure about it :( help me please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a good example of what you want right up at the top of [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite), which is a page everyone should read before they edit one character of an `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://other.example.com/$1

# is better expressed as..
Redirect / http://other.example.com/
```

Or, in your case,

```
Redirect / /beta/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/beta
```

to your .htaccess file in the root directory (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it pretty simple (no .htaccess modification required).

Edit the headers of index.html file from your server main director (/).

Within the `<HEAD> ... </HEAD>` section add your redirection code, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/beta/somepage.html" />
```

Note that this should be located inside index.html of you main dir /.

For references see: http://devmain.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/html-auto-redirect-website-to-different.html

Hope it help.